# .filter on HTML table returns no data - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create a table which allows you to filter and sort JSON data contained in cats.json:

```
[{
                "breed" : "Abyssinian",
                "country" : "Ethiopia",
                "coffeePreference" : "espresso",
                "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Gustav_chocolate.jpg/100px-Gustav_chocolate.jpg"
            }, {
                "breed" : "Aegean",
                "country" : "Greece",
                "coffeePreference" : "medium roast, cream and sugar",
                "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Aegean_cat.jpg/100px-Aegean_cat.jpg"
}]
```

I am able to sort the data with the following approach. Basically I have carefully nested a series of callback functions. The code here shows how I sort and render successfully.

```
function renderData(cats){
        var output='<table id="indextable" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
        output+="<thead>"
        output+="<tr>";
        output+="<th> HeadShot </th>";
        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedBreedData()'>Breed</button></th>";
        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedCountryData()'>Country</button></th>";
        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedCoffeeData()'>CoffeePreference</button></th>";
        output+="</tr>";
        output+="</thead>"

    for (var i in cats) {
        output+="<tbody>" 

        output+="<tr>";
        output+="<td><img src='" + cats[i].picture+"' alt='missing cat picture'></td>"
        output+="<td>" + cats[i].breed + "</td>"
        output+="<td>" + cats[i].country + "</td>"
        output+="<td>" + cats[i].coffeePreference + "</td>"
        output+="</tr>";
        output+="</tbody>" 

    }
    output+="</table>";
    document.getElementById("catTable").innerHTML=output;
}            



function getData(){       
    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
        var cats = cats;
        renderData(cats);    
    });
}    


var sortCountry;
function getSortedCountryData(){       
    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
        var cats = cats;
        if (sortCountry!=true)
            sortData(cats,'country',1);
        else 
            sortData(cats,'country',-1);
        sortCountry ^= true;   
    });
}

var sortBreed;    
function getSortedBreedData(){       
    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
        var cats = cats;
        if (sortBreed!=true)
            sortData(cats,'breed',1);
        else 
            sortData(cats,'breed',-1);
        sortBreed ^= true;   
    });
}

var sortCoffee;    
function getSortedCoffeeData(){       
    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
        var cats = cats;
        if (sortCoffee!=true)
            sortData(cats,'coffeePreference',1);
        else 
            sortData(cats,'coffeePreference',-1);
        sortCoffee ^= true;   
    });
}
function sortData(cats, element, direction){
    switch(element) {
        case 'breed':
            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.breed < b.breed) ? -1*direction : 1*direction;});
            renderData(cats);
            break;
        case 'country':
            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.country < b.country) ? -1*direction : 1*direction;});
            renderData(cats);
            break;
        case 'coffeePreference':
            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.coffeePreference < b.coffeePreference) ? -1*direction : 1*direction;});
            renderData(cats);
        default:
            renderData(cats);
    }

}
```

The problem is in the filtering. I am basically trying a similar approach. In the HTML I have a field, which the data entered is captured. I am certain this is happening properly.

```
                    <label for="filter">Filter</label>
                    <input type="text" name="filter" value="" id="filter" onchange="filterCats()" />
```

Once the data is captured:

```
    function filterCats(){
                    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                    var cats = cats;    
                    var criteria = document.getElementById('filter').value;
                    filterCats2(cats, criteria);
                    });                              
            }



            function filterCats2(cats, criteria){
                var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed === criteria;});
                renderData(filteredData);
            }
```

This renders an empty table. The table headers are all that appear. I have also tried alert(filteredData); which returns undefined as does alert(filteredData[0]); and alert(filteredData[0].breed); returns nothing. Any help as to what is going on here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what criteria do you input? It seems no error when I try it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j92009zv/

Comment: @LinYuan Breed... And none of the criteria work for me. The table goes blank every time I try to filter.

Comment: @LinYuan I see! But the input has to be exact. I want to get it where Ab would return Abyssinian for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason cause this issue is your filter function is set full match to return.

If you wanted to filter with contains or start with condition, you should change your filter like below....

```
// case sensitive and start with
return c.breed.indexOf(criteria) === 0 ; 

// case sensitive and contains
return c.breed.indexOf(criteria) !== -1 ; 

// case insensitive and start with
return c.breed.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) === 0 ; 

// case insensitive and contains
return c.breed.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) !== -1 ;
```

a fixed jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/j92009zv/1/

Answer (score 1):

I have created your example here; https://jsfiddle.net/9xftex5o/3/ there is no `$.getJSON()` calls as the cats object is included as `data`.

Your code to render the filtered results worked but hooking up the filter function for the change event didn't.

The filter function can be;

```
function filterCats() {
    var criteria = document.getElementById('filter').value;
    var cats = data;
    var filteredData = cats.filter(function (c) {
        return c.breed === criteria;
    });
    renderData(filteredData);
};
```

To hook up the event;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cats = data; // initialise data instead of $.getJSON
    renderData(cats); // show results
    $('#filter').on('change', filterCats); // event hook
});
```